# Show image after clicking a button

Tags: php

I am using a PHP script to write in an image.

Source: http://papermashup.com/demos/php-gd-image-and-text/

I want to hide the image and after clicking the "Update Image" button the generated image would then be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery Hide(); , show() function to achieve the functionality.

If you can put a code snippet here it will help people to understand the problem more clearly

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem because php gets executed only once on your page unless you have a refresh thing happening... So image should be there just that its hidden and we are changing the css property of the element...

Comment: the link that you are giving in image src is it only returning a jpeg image or other html elements as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for this.
Basically, php only runs once before the page is loaded, so it can't change the contents of the page after it's loaded.

You can either use document.InnerHTML (look it up) or jquery .load

Comment: Code below. I used javascript, but it is showing the image just for a second.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery like

Suppose your `input button`  has id like `clickme` and image which you want to hide has id like `hideme` then bind a jQuery event to this.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  $('#hideme').hide();
});
```

Just include basic jQuery libraries to your page.

Comment: Image : <div id="hideme" style="display:none">
<img src=<?=$filename;?>?id=<?=rand(0,1292938);?>" width="800" height='600'/>
</div>
Button : <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Image" id="clickme"/>                                                              Your code : <script>
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
  $('#hideme').hide();
}); 
</script>

Comment: Why you give display:none ? If its already not showing then how could you hide it again

Comment: after removing display:none, now it's showing the default image like the source link

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <img src=<?=$filename;?>?id=<?=rand(0,1292938);?>" width="800" height='600'/>



    </div>


 <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Image" onclick="showHide()"/>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide() {
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

I used this. Is working, but it shows generated image for just a sec, then it's refreshing.